# RPi Stand-Alone WiFi Network

Tags: networking, wifi

I am trying to create a WiFi Network that I can connect computers to. Also I would like to plug an old phone with Hamshack Hotline on it into the raspberry pi. I don’t have rhe ability to connect it to the internet and I was wondering if this is possible to do and if there are any tutorials.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure your Raspberry Pi to act as a WiFi access point. This involves installing and configuring software such as hostapd and dnsmasq to create the access point.